# How to create a list from an array of z-scores in R?

Tags: r

I have an array of z-scores that is structured like num [1:27, 1:11, 1:467], so there are 467 entries with 27 rows and 11 columns. Is there a way that I can make a list from this array? For example a list of entries which contain a z-score over 2.0 (not just a list of z scores, a list which identifies which 1:467 entries have z > 2).

Comment: I don't quite follow. What are the dimensions of this array? The three indicies make it seem like a 3-D array and I didn't know this was possible in `R` without making lists of 2-D matrices.

Comment: The dimensions are the same as what appears in the structure, 27 11 467. Perhaps it is a list of 2d matrices -  467 matrices with 27 rows and 11 columns each. The "class" command returned array but it does look like a list of matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Say that your array is called `z` in your R session. The function you are looking for is `which` with the argument `arr.ind` set to `TRUE`.

```
m <- which(z > 2, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

This will give  you a selection matrix, *i.e.* a matrix with three columns, each line corresponding to an entry with a Z-score greater than 2. To know the number of Z-scores greater than 2 you can do

```
nrow(m)
# Note that 'sum(z > 2)' is easier.
```

and to get the values

```
z[m]
# Note that 'z[z > 2]' is easier
```